# Can't clear cookies in spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, axios

Here's the spring configuration. Secure cookie class is just a factory for cookies.

```java
public class SecureCookie extends Cookie {

  public static final String accessTokenKey = "access_token";
  public static final String refreshTokenKey = "refresh_token";

  public SecureCookie(String name, String value) {
    super(name, value);
    this.setHttpOnly(false);
    this.setPath("/");
    this.setSecure(false);
    this.setMaxAge((int) Duration.ofDays(60).toSeconds());
  }

  public static SecureCookie delete(String key) {
    SecureCookie cookie = new SecureCookie(key, null);
    cookie.setMaxAge(0);
    return cookie;
  }
}
```

I've tried deleting cookies with the appropriate handler, called `deleteCookies` method, nothing worked.

```java
 http.logout(logout ->
      logout
        .logoutUrl("/api/auth/logout")
        .addLogoutHandler(
          new CookieClearingLogoutHandler(
            SecureCookie.delete(SecureCookie.accessTokenKey),
            SecureCookie.delete(SecureCookie.refreshTokenKey)
          )
        )
        .logoutSuccessHandler(
          (new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT))
        )
        .deleteCookies(
          SecureCookie.accessTokenKey,
          SecureCookie.refreshTokenKey
        )
        .logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:3000")
```

I'm making request with axios, here's the code for that

```js
const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/logout", {
      withCredentials: true,
});
```

Credentials are included and I'm getting no errors on the front-end. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Spring works, the problem was with the axios,
Instead of:

```js
const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/logout", {
      withCredentials: true,
});
```

object containing withCredentials should be placed as the third parameter like this:

```js
 const res = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/logout",
      {},
      { withCredentials: true }
    );
```